# Is it possible to rename a file in an old already-pushed branch?

Tags: git, egit

I migrated an old SVN repository to Git, and now my fellow Windows-using colleagues have a problem because in one folder there is a file containing colons, which is forbidden by Windows, and Eclipse's EGit chokes on this file.

I tracked down this file (it is really only one) and did a `git mv`, so the most recent commit can be correctly checked out.

Is it possible to rename this file by changing history without creating a new commit, so it looks as if it always contained underscores instead of colons?

The only way I can think of by now is to go to the check-out of the old SVN repository (I still have that), amend the offending commit, dump the repository from my gitlab and push everything again. But I wonder if there is a short cut around...